# Find max/mean/min of the a subset in R

Tags: r, subset

A simple question but I can't seem to figure it out. I want to find the maximum value in a subset of my data frame.

To my knowledge, it would look something like:

```
max(data.frame$vector1)[data.frame$vector2=="1",]
```

but I get the error message of incorrect number of dimensions.

This text is then supposed to be used as a logical test in another subscript

Comment: Try `max(dataframe$vector1[dataframe$vector2=="1"])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your indexing command is wrong.  Try

```
 max( dataframe[ , "vector1" ] )                              ## all of vector1
```

for all, and

```
 max( dataframe[ dataframe[,"vector2"]==1 , "vector1" ] )     ## subset
```

which you can write *in long form* as

```
 sdfind <- dataframe[,"vector2"]==1
 max( dataframe[sdfind, "vector1"])
```

You can also use the `subset()` function, or create a temporary variable, or even apply the `summary()` function at all values of `vector2`, or ..

Comment: It works on a test dataframe I made,but when running it on my data set it gives NA,even though none of the vectors contain. vector is vector with years (given as a factor) and vector 1 is weeks (given as numeric).

Comment: Learn to work with factors / convert with factors eg by searching on '[r] factors'. It's all been explained over and over before.

Comment: Your method worked :) the vector I referred to had been overwritten with some mumbo-jumbo :P