# Median of a subset of columns where value of other columns is 1

Tags: r

Very similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435810/getting-median-of-a-column-where-value-of-another-column-is-1-in-r), however there are some fundamental differences.

I have a data set of a Timestamp, 4 measurement columns, and 4 state columns:

```
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1409544002, 1409544006, 
1409544010, 1409544014, 1409544018, 1409544022), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), B = c(20.77579, 
21.05727, 21.81632, 21.36299, 21.18629, 21.34721), C = c(16.25537, 
16.45496, 16.70933, 16.1526, 16.60963, 16.76558), D = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), SA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"0"), class = "factor"), SB = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), SC = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), 
SD = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"0"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Timestamp", "A", "B", 
"C", "D", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to calculate the median of the columns that are on, as indicated by a 1 in the S* columns.

So far I can find which measurement columns to use row by row using this:

```
foo[i, c(which(x = foo[i, 6:9] == 1, arr.ind = FALSE) + 1)]
```

where `i` is the row number.

And this is as far as I get without my code getting too complicated. I was thinking I could create a new data frame by binding the columns I got with the line of code above (after a row by row `for` loop) to the Timestamp, fill in empty spots with NAs, calculate the median of that data frame, and finally bind the median to the original data frame. But there has to be a better way!

Any ideas?

Edit:

Output should look like this:

```
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1409544002, 1409544006, 
1409544010, 1409544014, 1409544018, 1409544022), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), A = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), B = c(20.77579, 
21.05727, 21.81632, 21.36299, 21.18629, 21.34721), C = c(16.25537, 
16.45496, 16.70933, 16.1526, 16.60963, 16.76558), D = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), SA = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"0"), class = "factor"), SB = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), SC = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "0"), class = "factor"), 
SD = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"0"), class = "factor"), Median = c(18.51558, 18.756115, 
19.262825, 18.757795, 18.89796, 19.056395)), .Names = c("Timestamp", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "SA", "SB", "SC", "SD", "Median"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What's your intended result for the example data?

Comment: @Thomas I've added the result data frame.

Comment: Sounds like a job just begging for the `plyr` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little messy because your `S*` columns are factor. If you converted them to numeric or logical you could skip much of the second line of code below:

```
w <- grepl("^S", names(foo))
m <- matrix(as.logical(as.numeric(as.matrix(foo[, w]))), ncol = sum(w))
foo$Median <- apply(`[<-`(as.matrix(foo[,LETTERS[1:4]]), !m, NA), 1, median, na.rm=TRUE)
foo
#             Timestamp A        B        C D SA SB SC SD   Median
# 1 2014-09-01 06:00:02 0 20.77579 16.25537 0  0  1  1  0 18.51558
# 2 2014-09-01 06:00:06 0 21.05727 16.45496 0  0  1  1  0 18.75612
# 3 2014-09-01 06:00:10 0 21.81632 16.70933 0  0  1  1  0 19.26282
# 4 2014-09-01 06:00:14 0 21.36299 16.15260 0  0  1  1  0 18.75780
# 5 2014-09-01 06:00:18 0 21.18629 16.60963 0  0  1  1  0 18.89796
# 6 2014-09-01 06:00:22 0 21.34721 16.76558 0  0  1  1  0 19.05640
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain or point me towards a resource explaining ``[<-``? I've never seen that before.

Comment: @amzu `[<-` is assignment to a subset of the lefthand side (it's the same as something like `a[b] <- c` but instead written as `[<-(a,b,c)` and does not change the original `a` object. I use that construction in order to reduce two lines of code to one.